# MySQL procedure returns NULL when similar sql query gives an result

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

When I use the query:

```
SELECT game_id FROM games_players WHERE player_id = 1 LIMIT 1
```

I got an result:

```
game_id
-------
      1
```

But when I run it as an stored procedure (on the same table, of course):

```
CREATE FUNCTION `start_game` (player_id_1 INT(11) UNSIGNED) 
    RETURNS INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
SELECT game_id INTO @game_id_1 FROM games_players WHERE player_id = 1 LIMIT 1;
RETURN @game_id_1;
END
END
```

for:

```
SET @p0='1';
SELECT `start_game`(@p0) AS `start_game`;
```

I got:

```
start_game
----------
      NULL
```

Why the procedure does not returns `1` and gives me `NULL` instead?

### edit:

Just the same behavior for any of the following **as a body of my procedure** (most of those tries are based on comments):

`order by` (it's always a good thing to do when you limit the result):

```
...
SELECT game_id INTO @game_id_1 FROM games_players WHERE player_id = 1 ORDER BY game_id LIMIT 1;
RETURN @game_id_1;
...
```

`player_id_1` instead of hard-coded `1` (if even hard-coded `1` doesn't work, then...):

```
...
SELECT game_id INTO @game_id_1 FROM games_players WHERE player_id = player_id_1 ORDER BY game_id LIMIT 1;
RETURN @game_id_1;
...
```

no limits! (I know that the result consists of one and one only value).

```
...
SELECT game_id INTO @game_id_1 FROM games_players WHERE player_id = 1;
RETURN @game_id_1;
...
```

Comment: A `Function` is not the same thing as a `Stored Procedure`...

Comment: Do you need to declare game_id_1 or something?

Comment: @shawnt00 not at all, it's temporary (note `@`). Anyway, when I use "normal" variable without `@` and `DECLARE` command before the result is just the same.

Comment: @Siyual indeed, but there's not much of a difference in case of MySQL. Function always returns an value and its parameter is equivalent to procedure's `in` parameter. Also, they are commonly used like synonyms (even if it's not 100% correct) and they are being put together in same paragraphs of documentations etc. I see "stored procedure" label as a shortcut for both of them sometimes.

Comment: I don't know a lot of mysql. Try declaring a value and initializing it. See which one comes back, null or initialized value. I suspect the value isn't getting assign by the `select`.

Comment: @shawnt00 as I said, for declared and assigned value (`DECLARE game_id_1 INT(11) UNSIGNED; SELECT game_id INTO game_id_1 FROM games_players WHERE player_id = 1 LIMIT 1;`) the result is just the same). If I declare it as e.g. `2` (no matter if it's temporary or not) and return it, I get `2` as expected.

Comment: You've got a LIMIT without an ORDER BY. The order will be determined by the query plan - and may be different between your function and your statement. So whether this is the issue or not I would definitely use ORDER BY. Also `SET @p0='1';` probably should be `SET @p0=1;` as it is an int. Not sure whether this will make a difference or whether MySQL will automatically cast it.

Comment: @shawnt00 If using words "as I said" harms you so much, then I guess that it's more of your not mine problem, sir. And the "as I said" part was for the "declared" more then "assigned" part - I don't pay so much attention to such silly things (I'm not a paranoiac).  However yours "I'll give you the benefit of the doubt as English is not your primary language" it's clearly an personal offense.. but whatever.

Comment: @AndyNichols The `SET @p0='1'` was auto-generated by phpMyAdmin, but unfortunately even when I hard-coded `WHERE player_id = 1`, the results stays the same. Same with and without `order by` and `limit`, `distinct`. However thanks for the tip, I have indeed forgot to add `order by` (I am sure to get 1 or none results, but I add `limit 1` to check if that was the problem).

Comment: It was a tone thing. "as I said" usually suggests irritation. I was serious about the benefit of the doubt and I actually meant no offense by that. Nevertheless there are a lot of jerks on here and I get tired of it pretty fast.

Comment: @shawnt00 from reading few of your comments on other topics ("I must be an idiot for not wrapping my head around it all in like 14 seconds... I'm so sick of stackoverflow." etc. from last month), I guest that the only irritated person here is you. Let's not continue the war here.

Comment: Yup. Did you bother to look at any of my answers though?
I apologize to you. I do genuinely appreciate how difficult English is and how hard it is for all of us to write quickly and clearly.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. In my [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ae8f/1) everything works as expected.